# Installing Multiple Postgres or Mysql instances with same version in RHEL

Tags: hadoop, postgresql-9.3, hortonworks-data-platform, mysql-5.6, rhel7

We're provisioning a Hadoop cluster based mainly on the Hortonworks distro, and we're testing installation procedures on a single Azure RHEL instance as a practice.

Ambari, Hive, Oozie and Ranger all require database instance/s. I was advised that I should have separate database instances for all of them (no single point of failure) and get the same version for ease of operation and maintenance. (I understand that in actual cluster, these databases instances are probably located in different nodes).

I am picking between PostgreSQL 9.3 and MySQL 5.6. Is it possible to install multiple instances (3-4 installations) in RHEL with same version? If so, can you advise some useful tips or point me to some documentation (as most of documentations I have seen are multiple installations with different versions)?

Comment: IMHO that strategy of using one dedicated instance per service creates **multiple SPOFs**, although it confines the failure to a single service at a time. Under the assumption that these services are really independent *(guess what happens when Ranger is down and HiveServer2 has to check the security policy before letting a user access a table...?)*

Comment: In the database world, the standard practice for **High Availability** is to run two shared instances with Master/Slave replication. When the Master instance stops responding (or is shut down for maintenance) then the Slave steps up, and the JDBC clients have to switch *(i.e. make sure you use a driver that supports DB failover and that the URL contains all required info!)*

Comment: Cf. http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/admin_ha_hivemetastore.html for example -- just alludes to the DB setup, but HortonWorks is even more allusive https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.3.4/bk_hadoop-ha/bk_hadoop-ha-20151221.pdf

Comment: Bottom line: find an experienced DB guy/gal and let him/her setup your repository for you (including scheduled backups, monitoring, etc.) That's not a job for a code jockey. The problems to address are different.